# How to order the id in serializers in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

when I try to sort my id in my serializers it gives me an error : `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'all'`.

Here is the code of my serializers :

```
class DatasetPidTrierSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dataset
        fields = ['id']

    def get_id(self, instance):
        songs = instance.id.all().order_by('id')
        return DatasetPidSerializer(songs, many=True).data
```

Here is the beginning of it : [model Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHk3f.png)

thank you for your help

Comment: This part of your code `instance.id.all()` suggests you are trying to access a related field? Can you share the related model?

Comment: Do you wanna get the list of `Dataset` objects?

Comment: yes but I want it to be sorted in ascending order of id

Comment: Where is the `DataSet` model? The image is the `DataFile` model.

Comment: oops I corrected the image

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to set `id` field in `Dataset` model. Django will do that automatically for you. You can define just two fields `pid` and `iddatta_resolution`.

```
class Dataset(models.Model):
    pid = models.ManyToManyField(
        ...
    )
    iddata_resolution = models.ForeignKey(
        ...
    )
```

And then in the serializer, you don't need to define `id` field. Because the default order will be `id` field automatically by Django.

```
class DatasetPidTrierSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Dataset
        fields = ['id']
```

Comment: thank you but to sort them out

Comment: To sort them out, you need to add the code in the view, not in the serializer class.
So could you please add the code in the views.py file?